# How can I sync my Palm Centro phone's calender and tasks to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, palm

Would like to stick with the Palm Centro on Verizon as it is one of the few decent smart phones with calender and tasks that doesn't require buying the data plan.  I've had luck syncing with Outlook 2000 on XP but now am moving on to Windows 7 and having a hard time.  Willing to buy a newer version of Outlook or a 3rd party tool if that's what it takes.  Not worried as much about syncing contacts but would be nice to back them up to the PC if possible.

Comment: +0. I'm using a Linux distribution which was released in 2013, yet J-Pilot syncs with my Palm Treo 700p perfectly. Please either: 1. Sync with an older version of Windows, perhaps on an old computer. Or: 2. Edit your question to indicate what's wrong. Or: 3. Back up your PC, shrink your Windows partition, then try installing the latest LTS release of Ubuntu Linux alongside Windows. Then, install J-Pilot into the Linux partition. If you get stuck, post another question. Good luck! Please let us know what you do in the end.